# How to handle Feature changes in a model deployed?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

I implemented and deployed with Flask an XGBoost model for a classification problem. But being aware that features importance can change over time to predict probability of label for new data, I implemented a Cron so that the model can be retrained every two weeks.

But I don't know how I can handle new features since I would have to wait a great volume of data to retrain the model to take into account this new feature ?

Is there an alternative of model deployment to this problem ?

Comment: Maybe you could try training a model w/ and w/o the new feature and compare performance on a held out validation set to see if the model does better with the new feature? This way you wouldn't have to decide when you have enough data to incorporate the feature, you let the model tell you when it has enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response but my problem is about a case where I already deployed my model (it is used to predict on real time basis). And let's say that there's a new feature (that I know can be important but it's new) and I don't have information in older observations about it. I would have, then, to wait a great volume of data to retrain the model with a Cron. But how can I handle this ? And is there another way ?

Comment: I'm suggesting you train a new model on just the data that has all the features you want and see how it compares. Without knowing more about your specific problem I cannot know if this suggestion is doomed for failure or not.